# Sort array after deleting value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

how can I sort an Array after deleting one value?

e.g. `{1,2,3,4,5}` --> `{1,2,null,4,5}` --> `{1,2,4,5,null}`.

```
public boolean removeNumber(int accountNumber) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Account.length; i++) {
        if(Account[i].getAccountNumber() == (accountNumber)) {
            Account[i] = null;
        }
```

Comment: What is `Account`? Is it an `Integer[]`?

Comment: Account is an array of type Account

Comment: so why you compare an account with a number?

Comment: Thats an other issue I havent resolved yet. But number must be int.

Comment: if `Account[i]` you can't compare to an int (and comparing is with == and not =) 
I'd suggest you *EDIT* and explain better or you'll question will be closed soon ;) Why would you remove an account ? because of what element ? (give Account class)

Comment: Please edit and add Account class definition and fields

Comment: so you want to remove by position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your original array is already sorted, and assuming that only one `Account` can have that particular `accountNumber`, there is no need to sort the array again. Just locate the element to remove, then shift everything after that element down one position, and null out the newly-freed element.

I've renamed the `Account` field to `accounts` to follow Java naming conventions, to make a clearer distinction between the array (`accounts`) and the class (`Account`), both for the future developers looking at the code, and for the Java compiler.

```
public boolean removeNumber(int accountNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if (accounts[i].getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) {
            System.arraycopy(accounts, i + 1, accounts, i, accounts.length - i - 1);
            accounts[accounts.length - 1] = null;
            return true; // Found and removed
        }
    }
    return false; // Not found, so nothing removed
}
```

Now, if you insist on sorting the array, you can do it like this in Java 8+:

```
Arrays.sort(accounts, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Account::getAccountNumber)));
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i was looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this way to achieve this :

1. You need to find the `accounts` that have the `accountNumber` you're looking for
2. you set them to `null` on the `array`
3. You sort the `array` with a `custom Comparator` :

   - if an element is `null` it has to go at the end
   - if both are `not-null` you compare their `accountNumber`

```
public boolean removeNumber(int accountNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Account.length; i++) {
        if (Account[i].getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) {
            Account[i] = null;
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(Account, (o, p) -> {
        if (o == null)
            return 1;
        if (p == null)
            return -1;
        return Integer.compare(o.getAccountNumber(), p.getAccountNumber());

    });
    return true;
}
```

---

Tips :

- follow naming conventions : `camelCase`for attriutes ==> `Account[]` becomes `account[]`
- use `.equals()` when you are comparing object, for an `int` `==` is right